# Converter timestamp JS para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para converter este código JS para PHP:

```
A = new Date(2020,1,1,0,0,0).getTime();
```

Apesar que o resultado sempre "será":

```
1580522400000
```

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', '2020-2-1');
echo $d->getTimestamp();

1580580050
```

Mas o resultado não está batendo.  Pois tem os segundos acredito eu.
Como retornar o resultado `1580522400000` com PHP?

Comment: De forma procedural: `date("U", strtotime("2020-01-01"));`

Answer (score 2):

O JavaScript gera o valor em milissegundos, e o PHP, em segundos. Para poder compará-los, multiplique o valor do PHP por 1000, ou divida o do JS por 1000 e pegue a parte inteira.